# Ubuntu 21.10 on Dell XPS 13 9310 WiFi Killer AX500s DBS stopped working in kernel 5.13.0-21-generic

Tags: wireless, dell, xps, 21.10

**Edited after super helpful chat with @chili555 that I botched by trying too many things at the same time...*

The WiFi adapter works in kernel 5.13.0.20-generic, but in 5.13.0-21 it's inactive and remains inactive after multiple shutdowns/ reboots.  I checked that it's active in BIOS and it exists but does not work

```
$ lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6390 Wireless Network Adapter [AX500-DBS (2x2)]
       vendor: Qualcomm
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:72:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath11k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:182 memory:a2500000-a25fffff

$ lspci | grep Qualcomm
72:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm QCA6390 Wireless Network Adapter [AX500-DBS (2x2)] (rev 01)

$ sudo modprobe ath11k_pci

$ sudo dmesg | grep ath
[    4.611544] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xa2500000-0xa25fffff 64bit]
[    4.611573] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.612103] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: qca6390 hw2.0
[   10.337672] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: failed to register fw indication: -110
[   10.337692] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: failed to send qmi firmware indication: -110
[   39.931711] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: link down error during global reset
[   45.574642] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xa2500000-0xa25fffff 64bit]
[   45.575668] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: qca6390 hw2.0
[   45.630047] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: failed to set pcie link register 0x01e0c0ac: 0xffffffff != 0x00000010
[   45.630054] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: failed to set sysclk: -110
[   45.650253] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: link down error during global reset

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

It is not present in networkmanager or ifconfig, Bluetooth works though which I believe is the same device.  Super thankful for any ideas.

The ax500 device works in the 5.13.0-20-generic kernel with

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep ath
[ 4.804410] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xa2500000-0xa25fffff 64bit]
[ 4.804440] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[ 4.808036] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: qca6390 hw2.0
[ 5.085678] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: chip_id 0x0 chip_family 0xb board_id 0xff soc_id 0xffffffff
[ 5.085684] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: fw_version 0x101c06cc fw_build_timestamp 2020-06-24 19:50 fw_build_id
[ 5.258202] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0 wlp114s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 351.080712] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: link down error during global reset
[ 356.511270] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xa2500000-0xa25fffff 64bit]
[ 356.512356] ath11k_pci 0000:72:00.0: qca6390 hw2.0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe ath11k_pci` and: `sudo dmesg | grep ath` and,finally: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: nothing for the first two, something about bluetooth for the last

Comment: Let's try to provoke a response: `sudo modprobe -r ath11k_pci && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe ath11k_pci && sudo dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: nothing but total silence

Comment: Whaa?? Please reboot and try the last sequence again. Why do I get all the stubborn cases? :-((

Comment: Same result. I know, it's really weird. Happened yesterday after they rolled out a kernel update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131297/discussion-between-chili555-and-axtimwalde).

Comment: Argh! I made a big mistake

Comment: Sorry, I had tried too many things at the same time when you helped m in the chat. I had disabled the UEFI wifi stack option in BIOS because I did not know what it does.  This seems to disable the device...
I went back and booted the -20 kernel and the device works with that kernel!

Comment: Please file a bug with `ubuntu-bug linux` with this information. Thanks.

Comment: Done https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1950515 It looks like this is a recurring regression that has been going on forever.  A fix seems to exist https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214455 but the regression keeps making it into distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works again with the now released kernel 5.13.0-22.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot
```

and if you never want to see this again:

```
sudo apt purge linux-headers-5.13.0-21 linux-headers-5.13.0-21-generic linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-21-generic linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-21-generic
```

Comment: Is suspend/hibernate working ok with this card?

Comment: I would say most of the time. But this XPS 13 9310 certainly has more issues with suspend/hibernate than the 9370 that I had before.  I have not investigated whether those issues are related to the WiFi card or something else.  The most severe and frustrating is the computer NOT going to sleep but silently cook in the bag until the battery is out.  I had a few cases of WiFi not being functional after wake but could always remedy this by software off/ on.

Comment: Thank you @axtimwalde for answer. I've decided to buy XPS 9300 because of ax1650s inside of it.