# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi stopped working Wifi Adapter not Found

Tags: drivers, wireless

Since today, the Wifi on my Dell XPS laptop computer with Ubuntu 20.04 installed stopped working. It says, wifi adapter not found. As suggested here, [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), I created this output to diagnose the problem:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/crDcM8sdsY/

The reason why I can post this now, is that in the boot menu I went to --> Advanced Ubuntu options --> ubuntu with linux 5.10.0-1050 oem. If I boot normally, I can get no wifi connection. By default, it would boot ubuntu with linux 5.11.0 generic.

Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the same kernel regression that resulted in the same issue with newer version of Ubuntu as reported here [Ubuntu 21.10 on Dell XPS 13 9310 WiFi Killer AX500s DBS stopped working in kernel 5.13.0-21-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374546/ubuntu-21-10-on-dell-xps-13-9310-wifi-killer-ax500s-dbs-stopped-working-in-kerne)

I filed a bug report with Ubuntu https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1950515 and there seems to be a fix https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214455 so I expect a recent update that will remedy this, until then, it looks as if we have to boot an old kernel or plug a USB wifi stick.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So I understand, that it has to do with the kernel version and I should not try to reinstall the driver? I have now tried to install several newer kernel versions, but I keep getting an error message upon booting (has invalid signature
error: you need to load the kernel first). As suggested, I am now considering to revert to old kernel versions (as suggested in comment 3 and 9 on your link) But I do not know how to do that. Could you give or link me a description. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Do a full power cycle, i.e. shut the machine down, not just restart.
2. Press ESC a few times when you see the Dell logo (or earlier), this gets you into the grub boot menu.
3. In the grub boot menu, go to Advanced boot options, select the ...-20-generic kernel. Enter.

If the device is still not present, try the same, but first enter BIOS (F2 during boot sequence) and deactivate and re-activate the Wifi device and the UEFI Wifi stack under the Connectivity category. Then boot into the ...-20-generic kernel.