# Ubuntu 21.10 wireless card/adapter not found

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, dell

I have been 3 days w/o wifi on my Linux/Ubuntu machine with a Dell XPS-9500 and Qualcomm/Killer Wificard. I have tried every tutorial I could find on this topic with no luck.
When I type
`sudo lshw -C network` there is no wireless connection at all.
I have the ath11k driver installed, my kernel is linux 5.13.0-21-generic, and out of despair I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10, which still did not fix the issue.
I have reinstalled multiple kernel versions multiple times (5.14, 5.11..) and tried to follow this guide: https://mukaiguy.com/adding-wifi-drivers-to-ubuntu-linux-for-dells-xps-15-9500-with-ax500-f535fb42db70 However, whenever I try to build the kernel with make commands, I get error messages ('Error 2').

Any ideas what I should try would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
(wifi used to work fine under Linux until now, it is a dual boot machine, and under windows, wifi still works, thus no hardware issue I presume).

Comment: Testing hardware in situations like this is what a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment is for -- so you're not haywiring your installed system and possibly making the problem worse.

Comment: Please see: "I had disabled the UEFI wifi stack option in BIOS because I did not know what it does. This seems to disable the device... I went back and booted the -20 kernel and the device works with that kernel!" It's a comment here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374546/ubuntu-21-10-on-dell-xps-13-9310-wifi-killer-ax500s-dbs-stopped-working-in-kerne/1374783#1374783

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem that is reported for the Dell XPS 13 9310 which has the same wifi card:
[Ubuntu 21.10 on Dell XPS 13 9310 WiFi Killer AX500s DBS stopped working in kernel 5.13.0-21-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374546/ubuntu-21-10-on-dell-xps-13-9310-wifi-killer-ax500s-dbs-stopped-working-in-kerne)

and links to here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1950515

The older kernel builds 5.13.0-19 or 5.13.0-20 appear to work.
Install the old kernel and cold boot (shutdown and power on) instead of just restarting.

This appears to just be a regression in the 5.13.0-21 kernel build, but may be fixed in a newer build.

I have the same problem with my Dell XPS 15 9500 on Ubuntu 21.04.
I'm using the HWE (HardWare Enablement) kernel build.
linux-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
Upgrading from 5.11.0.38.39 to 5.11.0.40.41 breaks the wifi.
I fixed wifi by rolling back to my earlier btrfs snapshot of my rootfs before the update and did a cold boot.
I also turned off the automatic updates, so that it wouldn't automatically install the kernel with broken wifi again.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

I created another btrfs snapshot of rootfs with the wifi working and automatic updates disabled.